# iPad - DetailViewController programmatically

Tags: ios, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I'm working on an iPad app where I use UISplitViewController. I also use DetailViewController in which to display some information from XML, but the information is not displayed in DetailViewController but in MaterViewController. I really do not know how to fix it. Can you please help. Thank you

**There is code:**

```
-(void) showDetailsForIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    [self.searchBar resignFirstResponder];
    DetailViewController* vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailsViewController"];

    Slova* slova;

    if(isFiltered)
    {
        slova = [filteredTableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    else
    {
        slova = [self.slovoArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

    vc.slovoItem = slova;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:true];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that you're pushing the new `UIViewController` onto the stack for `self`, which is presumably the `MasterViewController`. Instead, create a new project using Apple's Master-Detail Application and you'll see how they do it.

***Caveat:*** they use Storyboards, but it is very possible to do this all in code.

In Apple's example, both the `MasterViewController` and the `DetailViewController` are visible from the start (in landscape).

Look how Apple's example sets `detailItem` (`slovoItem`?) for `DetailViewController`:

```
#pragma mark - Segues
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        NSDate *object = self.objects[indexPath.row];
        DetailViewController *controller = (DetailViewController *)[[segue destinationViewController] topViewController];
        [controller setDetailItem:object];
        controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.splitViewController.displayModeButtonItem;
        controller.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = YES;
    }
}
```

So, you'll have `DetailViewController` already visible and you'll just update its `detailItem` property.

Therefore, the following code exists in `DetailViewController`:

```
#pragma mark - Managing the detail item
- (void)setDetailItem:(id)newDetailItem {
    if (_detailItem != newDetailItem) {
        _detailItem = newDetailItem;

        // Update the view.
        [self configureView];
    }
}
- (void)configureView {
    // Update the user interface for the detail item.
    if (self.detailItem) {
        self.detailDescriptionLabel.text = [self.detailItem description];
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank for your help but if I use your code, when the application starts up this error: [ipaddetailViewController topViewController]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7b39fee0. I tried to have this code: if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString: @ "showDetail ']) {NSIndexPath indexPath * = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]; NSDA * object = self.slovoArray [indexPath.row];[[segue destinationViewController] setDetailItem: object];} This works, but if you set Storyboard Sequi - Replace, the application crashes.